# How to move thumbnails from under main image to right side of the main image?

Tags: c#, jquery, css

I have a div in which there is a main image and some thumbnails.
Currently, my thumbnails displays under the main image; however, I need them on the right side of the main image vertically.

Following is my current code:

```
<div id=album>
  <img id="main-img" src='<%="Web/images/" +Model.List[0]%>' style="width:150px;height:100px;">
  <% foreach (var thumbnail in Model.List) { %>
    <div id="thumbimg">
      <img class="thumbnail" src='<%="Web/images/thumbs/" + thumbnail%>' />
    </div>
  <% } %>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.thumbnail{
  float:left;
}
.thumbnail div{
  clear:both;
}
.thumbnail, #main-img{
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.thumbnail').on('click', function () {
    console.log('clicked');
    $(this).parents('#album').find('#main-img').attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace('thumbs/', ''));
  });
});
```

Comment: I see the id `thumbimg` used in a loop... `id` must be unique. Then I see `.thumbnail div` in CSS... but `.thumbnail` are `<img>` elements.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ways to approach this. Here's one

```
<div id=album>
  <img id="main-img" src='<%="Web/images/" +Model.List[0]%>'>   
  <div id="allthumbs">
    <% foreach (var thumbnail in Model.List) { %>
      <img src='<%="Web/images/thumbs/" + thumbnail%>' />              
      <br>
    <% } %>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
#main-img, #allthumbs{
  float:left;
  width:150px;
  height:100px;
}
#allthumbs{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: That was what I did originally.. If I divide it into div, my javascript doesn't work. All of them should be in one div. Can you please give me some other way/ approach?

Comment: @SFY: There's an extra coma `,` in `#allthumbs,{`

Comment: @toofaced: What JavaScript ?

Comment: if your main-img is higher than the stacked thumbnails, you don't need a separate div.

Comment: Another option would be to increase the margin below main image.

Comment: I have js for replacing thumbnail image to main image once thumbnail img is clicked. `   $(document).ready(function () {        
        $('.thumbnail').on('click', function () {
            console.log('clicked');
            $(this).parents('#album').find('#main-img').attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace('thumbs/', ''));
        });
    });`

Comment: @toofaced: Next time, edit your question instead of dropping unreadable code in comments. There is an "edit" link at the bottom-left of your question.